# How to fix this regexp?

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I have a regexp (,\s*?\n)(\s*?)) and according to https://regex101.com/ it should work. The only problem is that it isn't. What I want to achieve is:

`'some text,
)'`

will get converted to

`'some text
)'`

I know that if that regexp of mine would somehow work than the output string would be:

`'some text)'`

Is there any way to not move the ')' to the same line as 'some text'?

The sample that I used for testing:

```
declare
    l_example varchar2(32000);
begin
    l_example :='some text,
    )';
    dbms_output.put_line(l_example);
    l_example := regexp_replace(l_example, '(,\s*?\n)(\s*?\))', '\2');
    dbms_output.new_line;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_example);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this:

```
regexp_replace(l_example, '(,\s*?'|| CHR(10)||' *)(\s*?\))', '\2', 1, 1,'m');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=60ecfbde5c53bda1778dc1de0f10b1c0)

Comment: Great! Now it works! Thank you. Even regexp_replace(l_example, '(,\s*?'|| CHR(10)||' )(\s*?\))', '\2') gives back the correct result. So it looks like '\n' simply doesn't work. Where could I find the complete list of regexp symbols for oracle? Best I found is https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/develop/regexp/regexp_otn.htm and it doesn't contain CHR(10).

Comment: @M.Dawid - [see this page from the SQL Reference Manual (v11.1) for info on regular expression support](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/ap_posix.htm#SQLRF020)